# Each face of a rectangle Q ha measure zero in Jordan measure

Tags: integration, measure-theory

> **Definition**
>
> Let $A$ a subset of $\Bbb{R}^n$. We say $A$ has measure zero in $\Bbb{R}^n$ if for every $\epsilon>0$, there is a covering $Q_1,Q_2,...$ of $A$ by countably many rectangles such that
>   $$
> \sum_{i=1}^\infty v(Q_i)<\epsilon
> $$
>
> **Definition**
>
> If $Q=[a_1,b_1]\times...\times[a_n,b_n]$ is a rectangle of $\Bbb{R}^n$ then for any $i=1,...,n$ the sets $F_{a_i}=\{x\in Q:x_i=a_i\}$ and $F_{b_i}=\{x\in Q:x_i=b_i\}$ are called the $i$-th faces of $Q$.
>
> **Statement**
>
> Any face of $Q$ has measure zero in $\Bbb{R}^n$

Unfortunately I can't prove the statement so I ask to prove it. I specify that I use Jordan measure. So could someone help me, please?

Comment: What is $v$? The lebesgue measure?

Comment: @LeanderTilstedKristensen No, Jordan measure

Comment: $F_{a_i}$ and $F_{b_i}$ are themselves rectangles of measure zero, aren't they? And they surely cover themselves.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $F_{a_i}= \{x \in Q \: | \: x_i = a_i\}$ be an i'th face of $Q$. Then for any $\delta > 0$ the rectangle 
$$Q_\delta = [a_1,b_1] \times \dots \times [a_i - \delta,a_i + \delta]\times \dots\times [a_n,b_n]$$
is a covering of $F_{a_i}$. The jordan measure of $Q_\delta$ is
$$v(Q_\delta) = 2\delta \prod_{j\neq i} (b_j-a_j)$$
so for any $\epsilon>0$, we can choose 
$$\delta < \frac{\epsilon}{2\prod_{j\neq i} (b_j-a_j)}$$
such that
$$v(Q_\delta) < \epsilon .$$

Alternatively one could argue (depending on the definition of rectangle), that
$$F_{a_i} = [a_1,b_1] \times \dots \times \{a_i\} \times \dots \times [a_n,b_n]$$
is in fact a rectangle, and that $v(F_{a_i})=0$, and that $F_{a_i}$ is clearly a covering of itself.

Comment: Yes, "one could argue", as indeed I did in the comments.